# Filling NSMutableArray from Json Response

Tags: ios, objective-c

I am trying to fill an array of points for graphing. Here is an example of the data returned:

```
(
    {
    precipIntensity = 0;
    precipProbability = 0;
    time = 1398123660;
},
    {
    precipIntensity = 0;
    precipProbability = 0;
    time = 1398123720;
},
    {
    precipIntensity = 0;
    precipProbability = 0;
    time = 1398123780;
})
```

I can access the individual values by using:

```
responseArray[i][@"precipProbability"]
```

where i is equal to the index.

I am trying to fill an array with these points but I can't seem to get it to work. Can someone help?

I have tried:

```
 if (!responseArray || !responseArray.count){
 } else {
     for (int i=0; i > [responseArray count]; i++) {
         ArrayOfValues[i] = responseArray[i][@"precipProbability"];
     }
```

and

```
if (!responseArray || !responseArray.count){
} else {
    for (int i=0; i > [responseArray count]; i++) {
        [ArrayOfValues insertObject:responseArray[i][@"precipProbability"] atIndex:i];
    }
```

and the ArrayOfValues is always empty (null).

Comment: Post the code where you are having trouble. Point out the issue.

Comment: Did you initialize ArrayOfValues? Also use camelCasing for variable names. It should be `arrayOfValues` to differentiate it from classes.

Comment: i > [responseArray count] is obviously wrong. And I recommend writing "if (responseArray == nil || responseArray.count == 0)" or better yet just "if (responseArray.count == 0)". Or even better just "for (NSDictionary* dict in responseArray)"; no check for responseArray == nil or responseArray.count is necessary.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your `for` loop condition is backwards. You want:

```
if (!responseArray || !responseArray.count){
} else {
    for (NSUInteger i = 0; i < [responseArray count]; i++) {
        [ArrayOfValues addObject:responseArray[i][@"precipProbability"]];
    }
```

Also note the proper data type for `i`.

Answer (score 0):

it looks like your data is already in an array. if you'd like to copy them to a mutable array you can call

```
NSMutableArray *mut = [responseArray mutableCopy];
```

if your real goal is to parse the JSON objects into an Obj-C model object, you probably want to read up on `<NSFastEnumeration>`

Answer (score 0):

How about this:

`NSArray *array = [responseArray valueForKey:@"precipProbability"];`